# YIN Algorithm for realtime pitch detection

Tags: python-3.x, signal-processing, librosa

I'm currently working on a personal project that would allow me to use my electric bass a kind of controller for my computer (mainly games, but it could be used for anything as the idea is to bind a specific note to a keystroke), and I have a question about realtime pitch detection using librosa's implementation of the YIN algorithm and pyaudio.  I am using pyaudio's callback method for detecting the pitch that gets input by my bass through a hardware audio interface.  This code block is that callback function:

```py
CHUNK = 1024
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16 # .wav format dtype

def callback(in_data, frame_count, time_info, status):
    global unique_note_count
    in_data_dec = byte_to_float(in_data) # Convert audio byte data to float data

    # Remove noise from audio data if within precision limit
    for i in range(len(audio)):
        if audio[i] < PREC_LIMIT and audio[i] > -1 * PREC_LIMIT:
            audio[i] = 0

    pitches = librosa.yin(y=audio, frame_length=CHUNK, fmin=librosa.note_to_hz("B1"), fmax=librosa.note_to_hz("F4"))
    geo_mean = np.exp(np.mean(np.log(pitches)))

    note = librosa.hz_to_note(geo_mean)

    if unique_note_count.get(note) is None:
        unique_note_count[note] = 1
    else:
        unique_note_count[note] += 1

    return in_data, pyaudio.paContinue
```

The sample rate is determined by the program based on what the preferred input device uses, but it can also use the default device's sample rate if the preferred device cannot be found.  Right now, that rate is 44100Hz.  `byte_to_float` is a function I pulled from someone's github.  It was meant specifically for PCM conversions, and I don't think my problems are coming from this conversion, but just to be safe here is the relevant code for that:

```py
#Convert PCM signal to floating point with a range from -1 to 1. Use dtype='float32' for single precision.
def pcm2float(sig, dtype='float32'):
    sig = np.asarray(sig)
    if sig.dtype.kind not in 'iu':
        raise TypeError("'sig' must be an array of integers")
    dtype = np.dtype(dtype)
    if dtype.kind != 'f':
        raise TypeError("'dtype' must be a floating point type")

    i = np.iinfo(sig.dtype)
    abs_max = 2 ** (i.bits - 1)
    offset = i.min + abs_max
    return (sig.astype(dtype) - offset) / abs_max


# byte -> int16(PCM_16) -> float32
def byte_to_float(byte):
    return pcm2float(np.frombuffer(byte,dtype=np.int16), dtype='float32')
```

Once `callback` gets called by a pyaudio input stream, it converts the byte data to float so librosa can work with it, then `callback` removes any low-level audio signals to reduce noise (`PREC_LIMIT` is currently set to `1e-8`.  Is this a fine value for filtering out noise?).  Then, librosa uses the YIN pitch detection algorithm to make a "guess" at what pitch is being played.  After that, a dictionary that tallies how many times a note is guessed gets updated, and after a few frames are read, the program will output the note corresponding to that dictionary's statistical mode.  However, the guesses are often very wrong (often more than an octave off), and getting a correct note to be output (for testing purposes, G2) seems to be up to chance.

I have a couple questions about what I've implemented so far:

1. Is finding the mode from a set of guesses through the YIN algorithm a valid way to iron out chance guesses, or is this further messing up the final detected pitch?
2. In the variable `audio`, there are often many zeroes, sometimes more zeroes than actual data.  Why is this?  The audio that gets output to my speakers first goes through the interface, and the signal seems clear enough to me when I listen to it, so I don't think the problem is a matter of the signal being too quiet.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I do not think that PaInt16 returns bytes - but instead 16 bit integers. Try converting to float by dividing by 2**15 instead

Comment: I do not think librosa Yin implementation is well suited for real-time/streaming usage. If you just want a practical solution, I would recommend using one of the many audio to MIDI tools, and then write a Python script to convert MIDI to your game/keyboard events

Comment: @JonNordby `i.bits` evaluates to 16, so `abs_max = 2**(16-1)`.  I'm unsure of what you mean, if not that.

Comment: Tryint to interpret the input as bytes is at best superflous - or possibly causing a disasterous corruption of the signal. Specifically I mean the np.frombuffer(byte,dtype=np.int16) part. Save it / plot it / etc to verify.